# How To Access Value From Hidden Input Field Of Returned Partial View In Ajax Success?

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have partial view `_Index` in which there is `<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnRejectAdmissionn">Reject Admission</button>` and on click of this button a boostrap modal of id `myModalAdmRej` is shown which have textarea and a button `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnReject">Reject</button>` to add rejection remarks, and on click of this button an AJAX call is made to an action `RejectAdmission1` which redirect to partial view `_Index` and with value assigned in variable `result`.
Now, that value from result variable is assigend in tempdata `TempData["mgsId"]`. And that tempdata value  is assigned in hidden input field `<input id="inpMsgVal" name="abc" type="hidden" value="@TempData["mgsId"]" />` which is present in partial view `Index`and that partial view `@Html.Partial("_Index", Model)`
 is called in main view `Index`.

Now, what i am trying to do is to access the value of that hidden input filed

```
<input id="inpMsgVal" name="abc" type="hidden" value="@TempData["mgsId"]" />
```

when button `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnReject">Reject</button>` on modal is clicked to add rejection remarks.

Problem with my code is that even though the hidden field have value, on accessing that value on AJAX by `var getId = $("tr").find("input#inpMsgVal").val();` variable doesnot have that value `getId = ""`.
So, any assiatsnace with my code will be a great help. 
Below is what I have done till now.
Below is my main view `Index` where partial view is called and my ajax is also written in this view similarly modal which have that button to call AJAX is also present on this view.

```
     <div class="box-body">
            <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Full Name</th>
                            <th>Grade</th>
                            <th>Admission Status</th>
                            <th>Admission Date</th>
                            <th>Rejection Reason</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="studentrejectiontbody">
                        @Html.Partial("_Index", Model)
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Below is my partial view `_Index`

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <input id="inpMsgVal" name="abc" type="hidden" value="@TempData["mgsId"]" />

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.studentid, new { @id = "studentidforRejectectionadmission" })
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fullname)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.classname)</td>

    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rejectionreason)</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnRejectAdmissionn">Reject Admission</button>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Below is modal present in main view i.e `Index`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalAdmRej" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Reject Admission</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="rejectmodalbody" studentIdForRejection="">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment">Admission Rejection Remarks:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="rejectRemarks"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnReject">Reject</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my AJAX which is present in main view `Index` and is called on click of button present in modal which is also present on same view

```
<script>
$("button#btnReject").click(function () {
    debugger;
    var studentid = $("div#rejectmodalbody").attr("studentIdForRejection")
    var remarks = $("textarea#rejectRemarks").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/AdmissionRejections/RejectAdmission1',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { studentId: studentid, rejRemarks: remarks },
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
            var getId = $("tr").find("input#inpMsgVal").val();
            if (getId == "1") {


                $("textarea#rejectRemarks").val('');
                $("tbody#studentrejectiontbody").html(data);
                SuccessAlert("Admission Rejected Successfully", 5000);
                $("#myModalAdmRej").modal('hide');
            }
            else {
                $("textarea#rejectRemarks").val('');
                $("tbody#studentrejectiontbody").html(data);
                ErrorAlert("Student Has Not Doone Admission Yet", 5000);
                $("#myModalAdmRej").modal('hide')
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Below is are my controller actions

```
     public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var getList = ser.GetAllStudentForRejection();
        return View(getList);
    }
    public ActionResult _Index(string studentName,int studentId = 0, int result =0)
    {
        if (studentId == 0)
        {
            TempData["mgsId"] = result;
            var getList = ser.GetAllStudentForRejection();              
            return View(getList);
        }
        else
        {
            if (studentName != null && studentName !="")
            {
                TempData["mgsId"] = result;
                var getList = ser.SearchStudentForRejection(studentId);
                return View(getList);
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["mgsId"] = result;
                var getList = ser.GetAllStudentForRejection();
                return View(getList);
            }              
        }
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RejectAdmission1(int studentId, string rejRemarks)
    {
        var getData = ser.RejectAdmission(studentId, rejRemarks);
        return RedirectToAction("_Index", new { result = getData });
    }
```

Comment: Did you say you are getting the value in the controller method?

Comment: @JamesS what i am trying to say is that variable getData wll have value and that value is assigned into partial view parameter int result and in _Index action the value from variable result is assigned into TempData["mgsId"] and that tempdata is used as value in hidden input field of partial view _Index . Now i want to access that value form that hidden input field which is returned as partial view in ajax success